# How I can edit the checkout review table

Tags: magento, html-table, review

Where exactly the item prices, taxes and shipping costs are defined? I want to highlight only prices not other text.

Up to now I tried several quick&dirty changes in item, info and totals.phtml. For e.g. in info.phtml I added bgcolor='#ff0000'. This is just an example I added it in many places in item, info and totals.phtml. But I never got the price column.

`<tr><th bgcolor='#ff0000'><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
<th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
</tr>`

Any advice or hints?

Answer (score 1):

Make changes to these two files.

```
\frontend\default\YOUR-THEME-FOLDER\template\checkout\cart\render\simple.phtml
```

and

```
\frontend\default\YOUR-THEME-FOLDER\template\checkout\cart\render\default.phtml
```

Comment: sadly not the right files. I am looking for the REVIEW table, one step before sucess. Your advice is good for editing the cart table.

Comment: I found it by myslef: app\design\frontend\<yourtheme>\default\template\checkout\onepage\review\item.phtml; but up to now I cannot find the place where to adapt the taxes columns... in info.phtml I guess but nothing changes...

Comment: The path for the cart table renderer is at `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`. If not, refer to your theme's `checkout.xml` file for particulars; look at the `addItemRender` action under the `checkout_cart_index` node.

Answer (score 1):

Was dealing with this same problem when I came across your question.

You should change

```
 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
```

the rows for products come from this file.

if you are using your own theme then modify that theme

```
 app/design/frontend/enterprise/YOUR-THEME-FOLDER/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will depend on which theme you're using, but most themes won't change a lot regarding the CSS-classes of the order review table. The price column of the order review table is the last column, most themes (e.g., the default theme) add the class 'last' to the td-elements of the table.

Your CSS code could look like this:

```css
#checkout-review-table td.last { background-color: #ff0000; }
```

Comment: my problem is to find the specific column. and I am pretty sure that I will use the right template. however, no changes will affect. can you tell me which column in which template in magento standard implementation? (using 1.7.0.2 CE)